# How to add UIImages like animation using NSTimer?

Tags: ios, nstimer

I want to add a array of UIImages to UIImageView using NSTimer. Such that it will be like an animation. How to do it in iOS?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do it.

```
 // create the view that will execute our animation
 UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

 // load all the frames of our animation
 campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.gif"], nil];

 // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
 campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
 // repeat the annimation forever
 campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
 // start animating
 [campFireView startAnimating];
 // add the animation view to the main window 
 [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Source: http://web.archive.org/web/20120305060003/http://appsamuck.com/day2.html

Comment: That link goes to a 404 page and is *exactly* why link-only answers is a bad idea!